# Use videoTexture as opacityTexture

Tags: babylonjs

How do I use video (mp4) as alpha map in babylonJS?

In three.js applying  a video as texture is as simple as assigning the video texture to alphaMap (instead of the diffuse map).

Here's the expected result in three.js - [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/9hvs5Lej/1/).

I attempted to do the same in babylonJS to no avail. Here's what I have so far [babylonJs demo](https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#CHQ4T#153)

```
var mat = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("mat", scene);

var videoTexture = new BABYLON.VideoTexture("video", ["textures/babylonjs.mp4", "textures/babylonjs.webm"], scene, true, true);

mat.opacityTexture = videoTexture;
```

Any ideas are welcome. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `videoTexture.getAlphaFromRGB = true;` to use all three channels combined for the alpha. By default it only uses the red channel, which does not have enough variance in the source video for it to show.

The complete example:

```
var mat = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("mat", scene);

var videoTexture = new BABYLON.VideoTexture("video", ["textures/babylonjs.mp4", "textures/babylonjs.webm"], scene, true, true);
videoTexture.getAlphaFromRGB = true;
mat.opacityTexture = videoTexture;
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I don't think the issue is lack of red in the video. (It has plenty of blacks and whites). I think the problem is that when using video texture it no longer uses the Red channel as alpha but the alpha channel itself which doesn't exist in a video. Just to clarify. Thank you.